# How to implement SAML based authentication for an Angular 7.x application with Azure AD being the Identity provider?

Tags: angular, authentication, saml-2.0, adal

I'm building an Angular 7.x application where the identity provider will be Azure AD and have to authenticate the users using SAML. I haven't been able to figure out a solution/ example of such implementation yet. I need the users employee id and job title but have been asked not to use the graph api. Can someone help me with it?

```
MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
      tenant: 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX',
      clientId: 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX',
      redirectUri: 'https://localhost:4200/',
      endpoints: {
        'https://graph.microsoft.com': 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX'
      },
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    })
```

Comment: Check the guide and accompanying samples https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

Comment: Yes, I've implemented so far using this guide but it doesn't tell me how to use SAML protocol.

Comment: Hi. Did u get any solution for this ? even i need same

Comment: @ShreeramMuralidharan Hi Sheeram. Did you manage to implement SAML in your Angular app? It would be awesome if you could share your solution.

Answer (score -1):

There's Passport SAML and saml2-js but they are for Node / NPM.

Is that an option?

Otherwise, put something like Auth0 / Okta in the middle. Then go OpenID Connect to Auth0 as per above (Auth0 has their own sample) and SAML to the IDP.